# Multibit client synchronizing since 10 Days now

Tags: wallet, multibit

I can not access my wallet, since 10 days now, I have downloaded the bitcoin-qt multibit version 0.5.13. On my HP-window 7- 32 bit laptop successfully and I immediately received 2 transactions simultaneously which was successful too, I could only rehearse with my transaction on the screen for just few hours, since ten days now.
I have been trying to open my wallet and make some transaction with my coins, but when I launch the multibit client platform as usual the screen start downloading blocks and synchronizing with network, this will go on for the whole day and stop at a particular point without access to my wallets, it has finally stopped at synchronizing with network 119 blocks to download.

I had mistakenly created 3 more empty wallets with my first and original wallet while looking for means to bring back my wallet to life. The four icons of the wallets are visibly displayed on screen, I have even tried to reset my block chain and transaction to see if any of the wallets can pop up, but they seems to be clinically dead, because the synchronizing therein always stop at 88%.
The download and synchronizing manner of this multibit client platform had finally exhausted my internet bandwidth for the month, I think the slow performance of my computer may have contributed to this drama also.

MY COMPUTER: HP LAPTOP CORE 2 DUO T5750 - OS WINDOW 7 ULTIMATE SERVICE PACK 1, 32 BITS, 2GHZ, MEMORY RAM 1GB, I am using a 3G broadband HSDPA 7.2MBPS network.

disk transfer rate 4.8mbp/s, graphics 4.0mbp/s, ram 4.5mbps/s, processor 4.7mbps/s and the total base score 4.0

Computer troubleshooting report -- programme compatibility details --incompactible application -- (multibit) detected.

I am not too familiar with IT technical jargons, but this information might be usefull to whomever would help me out.
I do not even have the address of my first and original wallet off-head, but the wallet was protected with a password before it disappeared.

Questions: how can I recover my address and my first wallet, and how can I migrate with my wallet to a light client or hassle free web-wallet.

Concerned people, if there is anything like going to the 'file' in my download to recover my wallet there, please help explain in details as am new to the whole computer stuff. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used MultiBit, but according to the [Exporting private keys](https://multibit.org/help_exportingPrivateKeys.html) page in the documentation, you should be able to get the private keys. You can then import them to another client (local or web) and sweep the coins. For an example of how to do this with blockchain.info, see the [Moving a wallet between MultiBit and blockchain.info](https://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_movingAWallet.html).